# How to override Hashmap put function?

Tags: function, hashmap, put

I want to override hashmap put function. As by default property of map is to change the value of key if same name of key is present.
I want to make map which will hold old value of key.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it could be easier than you might think.
You could do something like this:

```
Map<K, ArrayList<V>> multiMap = new HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>();
```

The collection you have in mind is called a **multimap**. Google's Guava provides produciton-ready implementations. Have a look [HERE](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, if I figure it out correctly you can use 2 libraries for this purpose:
**Google Guava** and **Apache common collections**.

**Google guava:**

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1-android</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then you can implement like this:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
             multiMap.put("key1", "value1");
             multiMap.put("key1", "value2");
```

OR

I think this approach can also help you

**Apache common collections:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then implementation:

```
    MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
    multiMap.put("key1", "value1");
    multiMap.put("key1", "value2");
```